# Cannot multiply rectangle matrices in python with numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, matrix-multiplication

I want to multiply  vectors to create a ‍`n x m` matrix

```
from numpy import*

X = [0,1,2,3,4]
Bign = 4
Y = ones(Bign) #[1,1,1,1]

Z= X @ Y
print(Z) #[[0,0,0,0],
           [1,1,1,1],
           [2,2,2,2],
           [3,3,3,3],
           [4,4,4,4]]
```

but I got this error and I don't know what to do

```
*ValueError: matmul: Input operand 1 has a mismatch in its core dimension 0, with gufunc signature (n?,k),(k,m?)->(n?,m?) (size 4 is different from 5)*
```

PS: I'm in fact trying to optimize a bigger program so avoiding slow implementations as for loops.

Comment: It looks like you want an outer product. `@` does a dot product.

Comment: Oh yes exactly ! You're the boss

Answer (score 0):

You requirement show that outer function . Outer Function is defined in numpy library

```
X = [0,1,2,3,4]
B = 4
Y = np.ones(B) #[1,1,1,1]
Z= np.outer(X,Y)
print(Z)
```

Read the numpy library using different function .
Link :- [Library]